# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Test Not Passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through the railstutorial.org book, chapter 9. When running the test suite, I can't get rid of the following failure. All the code has been attempted by first typing it in and then by copying and pasting from the book.

```
...............F............................................

Failures:

  1) SessionsController DELETE 'destroy' should sign a user out
     Failure/Error: controller.should_not be_signed_in
       expected signed_in? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:69:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 8.28 seconds
60 examples, 1 failure
```

Here's the code for the test in sessions_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do

  it "should sign a user out" do
    test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
    delete :destroy
    controller.should_not be_signed_in
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end
```

The (I think) relevant portions of sessions_controller.rb:

```
def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

The sign_out method is found in sessions_helper.rb

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

def current_user
  @current_user
end

def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  self.current_user = nil
end
```

So, if I understand this correctly, the test, after signing in a factory user, is calling the SessionsController's destroy method, which calls sign_out (from SessionsHelper), which is explicitly setting self.current_user to nil. Then the test checks signed_in? with the line be_signed_in. Since the code sets self.current_user to nil, current_user.nil? should return true, !current_user.nil? should return false, which is what the test wants (controller.should_not be_signed_in).

Any help would be appreciated. I'm learning Ruby, Rails and TDD all at the same time, so I'm not sure where my problem lies.

Comment: Can you add the code for how you implement the current_user= function?

Comment: current_user=(user) returns @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token, and when looking at that I did find another mistake, as current_user was defined the same way, which checking the book, should return just @current_user. However, I changed that and I'm still getting the same error from the tests.

Comment: I apologize, signed_in? is found in sessions_helper.rb. I'll edit the question to reflect this and include the code for current_user= and current_user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are setting current user - you are only ever setting it to login from the remember token, you aren't ever allowing it to be set to nil. You might want to try the following:

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end
```