# rspec test fail - user sign out - Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial book Chap 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Found a similar question ( [Ruby on Rails Tutorial Test Not Passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917798/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-test-not-passing) ) , but its answer did not fit my issue. Tried to include as much relevant information as I could.

Rspec error:

> Failures:
>     1) SessionsController DELETE 'destroy' should sign a user out
>        Failure/Error: controller.should_not be_signed_in
>        expected signed_in? to return false, got true
>        # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in '

The test:

```
  describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do
    it "should sign a user out" do
      test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
      delete :destroy
      controller.should_not be_signed_in
      response.should redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end
```

SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def new
    @title = "Sign in"
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                         params[:session][:password])

    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Sessions Helper

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end

  private
    def user_from_remember_token
      User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
    end

    def remember_token
      cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil,nil]
    end
end
```

All help is appreciated. This isn't the first time I've run into an issue working through the book, but it's the first time I haven't been able to solve it (and like the other times, I'm sure it's my error :-)  ). I even browsed the git repo but am not sure what I've managed to do differently.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above with success.  I don't think the server should have anything to do with it as the error is generated by rspec.

Answer (score 0):

So, no promises here, but I too saw some strange rspec related session behavior that went away when I did this:

rake db:reset
rake db:migrate
Stop autotest with ctrl-c
Restart autotest
Stop the rails server with ctrl-c
Restart the rails server with "rails s"

I don't have a good explanation for why this might fix the problem, but it has for me.  Generally, I am so very impressed with the quality of Michael Hartl's tutorial.  When problems have arisen they were always the result of me doing something 'wrong.'  This particular issue, and another relate one in CH 11, left me thinking that some unexpected behavior could be attributable to the state of the db.  My badly formed Q&A for the CH 11 issue is here [Rails 3 Tutorial Chapter 11 "Validation failed: Email has already been taken" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5308307/657003)

Hartl does not go into recommended ways for bringing the db back to a starting point.  The above is my approach.  There may be better ones out there that I would be happy to see.

Comment: whoops, I meant to update this a while ago. I appreciate you commenting. My mistake was not running rake against test  like I had against development. So I was getting mixed results due to two difference database schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is because you `def destroy` twice in SessionsController?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  .
  .
  .

  def destroy
  end
```