# `raise_record_invalid` using FactoryBot with Rspec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm using `FactoryBot` to create fake data for my Rspec tests. My factory for the users is as follows:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "User#{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@email.com" }
  end
end
```

Creating a user creates a client automatically in my `User` model as an after action:

```
def initialize_client
  self.client = self.build_client
  self.client.setup_stripe
  self.save
end
```

And I have a factory for client as:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :client do
    user
  end
end
```

I created an Rspec file to test if the `client` gets build properly on creating a User as:

```
describe User, type: :model do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
end
```

But this raises the error:

```
raise_record_invalid': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Even though running `FactoryBot.create(:user)` creates the Client and User as accepted. I'm not sure what I need to change at this point

Comment: just wild idea. 1. kill your server 2. run rails db:setup 3. run rails db:setup RAILS_ENV=test

Comment: @KickButtowski just tried doing that, didn't help :/

Comment: even this rails db:setup RAILS_ENV=test?

Comment: @KickButtowski okay I just tried it with `RAILS_ENV` and it works. This is weird though, I'll accept it as the answer if you can add that. Do you mind explaining why I had to this though? Ty

Comment: post the answer for you. hope my explanation is enough for you to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To my defence, I am not so experienced with the FactoryBot.

You have using `create` in  `user = FactoryBot.create(:user)` , it is going to make record inside your database, so when you are trying to create same record, you will get the error.

1. [Read this for getting more info](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test)
2. [check this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308307/rails-3-tutorial-chapter-11-validation-failed-email-has-already-been-taken-er)

Do the following

1. Kill your server, so you do not encounter someone is using your database
2. run `rails db:setup`
3. run `rails db:setup RAILS_ENV=test`

Note: All

> rails db:setup

versions will help you to reset your database and run your seed file if there is any.

Hope my explanation was helpful for you to start **researching** and learning more ;)

Comment: You nudged me in the right direction, for anyone who stumbles to this post I ended up adding `database_cleaner` to my spec tests and this cleans up the transactions every time I run my tests

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I like to use a different solution, a.k.a. the [Faker::Internet](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/internet.md) portion of the Faker gem.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    email { Faker::Internet.safe_email(name: name) }
  end
end
```

```
2.5.7 :013 > user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
 => #<User:0x00007fb93a19f690 @name="Warner Hayes", @email="warner.hayes@example.net">
2.5.7 :014 > user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
 => #<User:0x00007fb938ddadf8 @name="Basil Smitham", @email="smitham_basil@example.com">
2.5.7 :015 > user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
 => #<User:0x00007fb938de16a8 @name="Mr. Winfred Daugherty", @email="daugherty.mr.winfred@example.com">
2.5.7 :016 > user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
 => #<User:0x00007fb939bd2168 @name="Elodia Bartell PhD", @email="bartell.elodia.phd@example.com">
2.5.7 :017 >
```